# select an hidden element with multiple class name

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-plugins

In the following html code, One of the div is hidden and the other one is not.My question is

1.how to select any element with multiple class names with hidden attribute

2.how to get the inner html when the html is hidden or shown

I tried,

```
 $('.middle-cont,.float-lft,.content-height').html() 

 $('.middle-cont,.float-lft,.content-height:hidden').html() //will this work
```

html

```
<div class="middle-cont float-lft content-height">
 some html
</div>

<div class="middle-cont float-lft content-height" > //This div is hidden
 some html123
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no comma's, commas will select all elements with either of the classes, while removing the comma's will select the elements that has all the classes :

```
$('.middle-cont.float-lft.content-height').html()
```

wether or not it's hidden makes no difference for this.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/DKjaZ/2/)

Comment: But in the fiddle when i run another without display:none attribute it doesnt alert the value,it only alerts the hidden value..

Comment: `.html()` only returns the HTML for the first matched element in the set of elements, not for multiple elements. You would have to iterate for that, see [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/DKjaZ/5/) !

Answer (score 1):

you don't need `,` to select element with multiple class....use `html()` to get the content.. (it doesn't matter if it is hidden or not)

```
$('.middle-cont.float-lft.content-height').html()
```

Answer (score 0):

Comma using as `OR` operator, you dont need it here so:

```
$('.middle-cont.float-lft.content-height').html()
```

It's not matter that your element is hidden or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
 var innerHtml = $(".middle-cont").filter(".float-lft").filter(".content-height").html();
 alert(innerHtml);
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dtN7y/1/)